# Unified Theory + Trick Magic Item would they work together to use magic items?

Tags: magic-items, feats, skills, pathfinder-2e

If you got [Unified Theory](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=859) and [Trick Magic Item](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=857) (Arcana) could you use magic items (EX - Scrolls, Wands, and Staves) from other spell traditions?

indigochild said on this [post](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/153478/28326) that the requirements are

- That you are using an action or skill feat.
- That whatever you are doing requires a Nature, Occultism, or Religion check.
- That the kind of check is determined by a magical tradition."

However I want to know how this applies to Trick Magic Item.

Comment: I removed your [new-GM] tag, which is intended to be about questions *related to* new GMs, not to indicate that you are one or have one. I moved your links to be in-line, and removed the not-tag from the title (it isn't necessary because of the tags)

Comment: [Related](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/180185/is-trick-magic-item-one-feat-or-four/180186#180186), I don't think you take Trick Magic Item "Arcana", although the question still holds up that you could use Arcana for any magical traditions' items

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### *Trick Magic Item* lets you activate items from other traditions on its own.

You don't need *Unified Theory* for this. The explicit outcome of using *Trick Magic Item* is that you can use things like scrolls and wands from other magical traditions.

Suppose Willhelm the Wizard wants to use a scroll to cast *Soothe*, an occult spell. If they have *Trick Magic Item*, they can attempt an occultism check to activate the item. *Unified Theory* isn't necessary here.

### Combining with *Unified Theory*

If you want to combine it with *Unified Theory* for other reasons, can you? As an example, let's go back to Willhelm the Wizard trying to cast *Soothe*. This time they have both *Trick Magic Item* and *Unified Theory*.

Willhelm tries to use the scroll, but can't activate because they aren't an occult spellcaster. So they decide to use *Trick Magic Item*. They can now attempt an occultism check to activate the scroll.

As they are using an action (and skill feat!) to make an occultism check as determined by the magical tradition of the scroll, they make invoke *Unified Theory*. Now Willhelm instead makes an Arcana check to activate the scroll. Since they must be at least legendary in Arcana to take *Unified Theory*, this is probably a pretty sweet deal.