# Is Trick Magic Item one feat or four?

Tags: feats, pathfinder-2e

[Trick Magic Item](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=857) shows up in the [feats lists](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?Traits=144&Skill=Arcana) for each of the skills associate with a magic tradition - Arcana, Nature, Occultism, and Religion. Most other skills, such as [Assurance](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=756), only apply to one skill even if they could be selected for multiple.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### *Trick Magic Item* in 1 Feat

*Trick Magic Item* is a single skill feat. You can read it on page 268 of the *Core Rulebook* where it appears printed only once.

The text of the feat makes it clear that this feat applies to all 4 magical tradition skills (Arcana, Occultism, Nature, and Religion). There is plenty of precedent for this, such as the *[Quick Recognition](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=826)* skill feat<sup>1</sup>.

It sounds like part of your confusion stems from how you located the feat on the Archives of Nethys. Odds are the site's developers added *Trick Magic Item* to lists for each of those four skills, so that users could find it where they intuitively expect it to be. It's an artifact of representing a book within a database table.

---

<sup>1</sup> For an list with more examples, see Ifusas's [answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/180185/is-trick-magic-item-one-feat-or-four#answer-180186).

Answer (score 3):

### Trick Magic Item is one feat

Trick Magic Item lacks the crucial line in other "multi-skill" feats,

> Choose a skill you’re trained in.

Trick Magic Item applies to all four of the skills, but is only one feat to take. This holds true for the other magic-tradition feats

- [Quick Identification](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=824)
- [Recognize Spell](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=834)
- [Assured Identification](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=2111)
- [Magical Shorthand](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=813)*
- [Quick Recognition](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=826)

*This one is less likely to apply to more than one